# Variables from Multiple columns lookup to insert new column in Power Query or Power Pivot

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, powerpivot, power-query

Apologies for the layout from below but it is a sample with 4 columns.

I need to insert the target from Table below in a new column, based on the Product (Quite a long list) together with the Priority (ranking 1 to 4 but only gave 2 below) which is also dependent on office or After Hours.

Can someone please help with a formula to auto - populate this either in Power Pivot or Power Query or both so I can use either.

Product Priority    Hours   Target
  A        1          OH      One
  A        1          AH      Two
  A        2          OH      Three
  A        2          AH      Four
  B        1          OH      One
  B        1          AH      Two
  B        2          OH      Three
  B        2          AH      Four

My raw data contains columns for Product,Priority and Hours. I also have a seperate table as indicated above with all products priorities and hours in columns 1, 2 and 3.

Thanks in Advance
Keith

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Query Merge feature for this.  It can connect 2 Queries together, using matching columns.  Queries can start from an Excel table.

There's a good description and walkthrough for Merge on the PQ support site:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Merge-queries-Power-Query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9

Comment: Thank you very much Mike. After an intense battle to ensure the formatting in each of the 3 columns were identical I was able to get this right.